# Android - Using Universal Image Loader in static class

Tags: android, android-image, universal-image-loader

Can I use Universal Image Loader lib in a static class? Meaning creating one instance of image loader and modifying it to static.

What is the best method to use this lib in different multiple fragments and classes? How can I  improve caching feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to use Universal Image Loader is to create a single instance when your App starts up and then get that instance throughout the app

Here is the App class

```
 public class App extends Application {

    public ImageLoader imageLoader;

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        return imageLoader;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // UNIVERSAL IMAGE LOADER SETUP
        DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
                .cacheOnDisk(true)
                .cacheInMemory(true)
                .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300))
                .build();

        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
                .memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache())
                .diskCacheSize(100 * 1024 * 1024)
                .build();

        this.imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        imageLoader.init(config);

        // END - UNIVERSAL IMAGE LOADER SETUP
    }
}
```

**Make sure** the application tag in AndroidManifest.xml has android:name=”.App” attribute

To get the instance, in an Activity

```
ImageLoader imageLoader = ((App)getApplicationContext()).getImageLoader();
```

outside Activity

```
ImageLoader imageLoader = ((App)context.getApplicationContext()).getImageLoader();
```

You can refer [this](http://devnextdoor.com/2016/11/28/using-universal-image-loader-in-android/) blog.

Answer (score 3):

**`ImageLoader.getInstance(); // Get singleton instance`**
the above line will provide a singleton. you can call it then perform your loading 
as the [doc](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) shows there is a [sample project](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/tree/master/sample) which you can download form github. this sample project shows how to use this library properly

Answer (score 1):

i recommend you to use Glide a very nice image loader lib, i myself has tried and happy using it.

this is what you need to read and implement for image caching and efficient use of lib

https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-getting-started

the official link
https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Comment: Can I use glide for getting video thumbnail from remote source?

Comment: @TunahanBayındır yes  you can use glide for the loading urls, it loads urls and caches it in the memory saving lot of memory

Comment: @darpan-s-raut I mean, can it get first frame of a remote video as thumbnail?

Comment: @TunahanBayındır check this link https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-thumbnails

Comment: @TunahanBayindir please up vote the answer if helped